# iPhone label is not updated

Tags: iphone, label

I want to update a label on an iPhone form from a separate  thread. The thread is running but the label is not updated.

here is my code

```
-(void)launchThread:(id)param;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;

...

-(void) launchThread:(id)param{
UILabel *control = (UILabel*)param;
NSMutableString *str;
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    control.text=str;
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    sleep(1);
}}

...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(launchThread:) toTarget:self withObject:timeLabel];
}
```

I guess the label's text is updated but not refreshed on the form. How do I refresh it?

I have tried to look for similar posts but they did not work for me. Sorry if I repeated the question.

Comment: Your outlet has been correctly set in IB, right?

Comment: Yes. I can set the label programmatically from the main thread. when the second thread start it sets the label to 0 and does not update it any more. however the output windows shows how new logs are added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jackslash is correct, you can only update the interface on the main thread (UI thread). I would suggest using `performSelectorOnMainThread` to update your UILabel. I think the syntax is something like:

```
[self.label performSelectorOnMainThread : @ selector(setText : ) withObject:str waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Not quite certain tho. Do some googling and you should be able to find a working example with it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark as answer for future users who stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS you can only use the main thread to update the interface.

There are two things you can do to update the interface from a thread very easily. Using a method of NSObject like so:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait];
```

And using blocks and GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    //code to execute on main thread
});
```

Comment: I tried to pass the self to the launchThread method and call updateLabel method from there. are there any other ways to update the label on events at a different thread?

Comment: i expanded my answer. Sorry it was short I was typing on an iPad. Not the best place to be answering these!